# Initialize member istream from either existing istream or from one created by class itself

Tags: c++, file, c++11, pointers, memory

I'm trying to figure out how I can have a single member variable that either represents a passed in `istream` or one that the class creates itself.

I figured that using a pointer to the `istream` could work if I dynamically allocate the `istream` that the class creates; however, the issue with that is that the `unique_ptr` will try to free non dynamically allocated memory.

Here's some code that reproduces the issue that I have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

class example {
public:
  explicit example(std::istream& i)
    : m_input(&i)
  {}
  explicit example(const std::string& path)
    : m_input(new std::ifstream(path))
  {}
private:
  std::unique_ptr<std::istream> m_input;
};

int main() {
  example e1(std::cin);
  example e2("./test.txt");
}
```

`e1` will try to free `std::cin`, which causes the error. I know I could have use more than one member like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

class example {
public:
  explicit example(std::istream& i)
    : m_i(),
      m_input(&i)
  {}
  explicit example(const std::string& path)
    : m_i(path),
      m_input(&m_i)
  {}
private:
  std::ifstream m_i;
  std::istream *m_input;
};

int main() {
  example e1(std::cin);
  example e2("./test.txt");
}
```

but I'm wondering if there's a way to do it with just one member variable

Comment: Streams aren't copyable? Did I miss something from your question?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ right they aren't copyable so I need to either have a member that's a pointer or a reference to the passed in stream. However, this clashes with the constructor where I create my own stream because if I want to use the same member variable (which is a pointer) I have to dynamically allocate. The issue with this is that I only dynamically allocate the pointer in the string constructor, and thus, when I try to deallocate, it'll be an error if the `example` was constructed from an existing `istream`. Make sense?

Comment: No, that stuff doesn't make sense, sorry. Elaborate about your use case and the problem you actually want to solve please.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ okay sorry if I am being unclear. I have a class that needs to read from an input stream. My goal is that I would like to be able to initialize that class' input stream from either an existing input stream or from a file path.

Comment: You can simply use a pointer member for such case.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ could you elaborate? If you look at my example code above, you can see that I have a solution to my issue which uses a pointer member in the second code example, but it requires that I use two member variables. I would like to be able to solve this problem using only one member variable.

Comment: Why do you need the constructor that takes a file path at all? If it's just for convenience I would remove that to keep both interface and implementation simple. Users of class `example` can already create a `std::ifstream` (which can be constructed from a file path) and pass that to class `example`.

Comment: @zett42 I think that's what I'm going to end up going with. I thought maybe I was missing something and it was simple to do, but the increase in complexity isn't really worth the extra convenience of not having to write just one more line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you might extend your approach with storing a pointer to the stream:

```
class X {
    public:
        explicit X(std::istream& stream)
            : stream(&stream, [](std::istream* stream){})
        {}

        explicit X(const std::string& path)
            : stream(new std::ifstream(path),
                [](std::istream* stream) { delete stream; })
        {}

    private:
        using StreamDeleter = std::function<void(std::istream* stream)>;

        std::unique_ptr<std::istream, StreamDeleter> stream;
};
```

Just add a custom deleter. In case of existing stream it does nothing. In opposite, if stream was manually created, it releases the stream.

Comment: I was just about going to answer in this direction. +1

Comment: Awesome thanks! Now that you've answered my hypothetical question of whether it **can** be done, do you think I **should** do it this way? It seems rather complex compared to having just an extra member.

Comment: @AR7 I suppose that adding an extra member is not the best option. With custom deleter you probably have a more flexible solution. I mean that adding new members for different cases makes the design quite awkward. In the same time, you might avoid it and have only a single member which knows how to release the resource (stream) properly.